# Block fadeout when mouse over or click event on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used below code to fade-out #widget in 10 secs and fade-in #floating_widget in 10.2secs. This works fine.

But, #widget container should not fade-out when i clicked or mouseover #widget container. Now, it fade-out automatically because of setTimeout code.

Please let me know how to fix this issue? Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div id="widget">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>

<div id="floating_widget">
  <h2>Hello World 2!</h2>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#widget').fadeOut('slow');
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#floating_widget').fadeIn('slow');
}, 10200);
$('#floating_widget').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#widget').show();
});
```

Comment: don't understand what u mean.. you want to stop fading out when u clicked or mouseover??

Comment: Yes @Zoedia . When user mouseover #widget container.. fadeout action should not happen

Comment: Try $('#widget').stop() which Stop the currently-running animation

Comment: $('#widget').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop();
    });   correct?

Comment: yes.. does it work?

Comment: actually that .stop() might only stop animation, means will only stop while animation is ongoing. and the animation will start only after a few seconds. So, if you want to stop continuing even before animation start, you might also want to clearTimeout() on that element too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got the right understanding of your question. It seems that you have a problem with the timeouts. You will have to clear them in a `onmouseover` function. Here is an example of the JavaScript:

```
var $widget = $('#widget')
var $floatingWidget = $('#floating_widget')

var widgetFadeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  $widget.fadeOut('slow')
}, 10000)
var floatingWidgetFadeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  $floatingWidget.fadeIn('slow')
}, 10200)

$widget.mouseover(function() { // https://api.jquery.com/mouseover
  // Remove the timeout to avoid triggering the fadeOut and fadeIn
  clearTimeout(widgetFadeTimeout) // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout
  clearTimeout(floatingWidgetFadeTimeout)
  // In case the element began the transitions stop them
  $widget.stop()
  $floatingWidget.stop()
  $floatingWidget.hide()
  $widget.show()
})

$floatingWidget.click(function() {
  $(this).hide()
  $widget.show()
})
```

I hope this will be useful for you!

Comment: he said 'clicked or mouseover' . Would be better with `$widget.on('click mouseover', function() { ... });`